# c# Avalonia Ui - Manage Column in Datagrid from a Grid without having an useless new Column

Tags: c#, datagrid, avaloniaui

The problem is that I have a Datagrid in a Grid.Row and my Datagrid's Columns work correctly but for no reason there is another one who fill the void on the left from the datagrid.

I use Avalonia Ui

I want to just have my four columns and don't want another one.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KDy7.png) you can see a picture and the code.

I hope that someone can help me ;)

```
<!-- Mid -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="Silver">
        <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" Items="{Binding People}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom de la machine"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adresse Ip" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adresse MAC" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Reveiller">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="WakeBtn_Click">
                                <Image Width="20" Source="C:\trd\original\WakeOnLanClientServer\WakeOnLanClientServer\wolClientAvalonia\Assets\reveil.png"></Image>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

so I believe the issue is that you have AutoGenerateColumns set to True. As the [docs](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/datagrid) mention, AutoGenerateColumns will "automatically generate for display in UI from the bounded data source." Since you are manually defining specific columns, you will want to change that to False.